# @requestbody doesn't work for set values model angular js to spring mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Hello I'm just a beginner in AngularJs and Spring mvc and I would like to send a table values from AngularJs model to spring controller (in the model of the table_database), so after use the submit button I can get the object like [**this one**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJWFU.jpg)

But the method of the controller doesn't work so my code is like thise;

```js
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/SAO" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public DProjetEtape NouveauEtapesProjet(@RequestBody DProjetEtape DProjetEtape) {
  
  DProjetEtapeService.saveProjet(DProjetEtape);
  
  System.out.println("DProjetEtape  "+ DProjetEtape);
  
  return DProjetEtape;
 }
```

```html
 
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Création d'un projet</title>
 <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/static/css/ol.css' />" type="text/css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/ol.js' />"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/OpenLayers.js' />"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/AngularJS1.2.js' />"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery.min.js' />"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
   body { background-color:powderblue; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="panel-body">
<fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border">Phases/étapes du projet</legend>
    <form data-ng-submit="submit()" name="myForm" data-ng-app="DProjetEtape" data-ng-controller="Controller_DProjetEtape">
<div class="row" >
 <ng-form>
        
     <div class="col-md-4">
     
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>Nom</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom"  data-data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.ordretap" >   
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>Date de publication AO</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date de publication AO" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.datpubao" >   
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>Date Ouverture des plis</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Ouverture des plis" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.datouvpl" >  
                            </div>
                       
                
            </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
           
                       
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>Durée estimative</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Durée estimative" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.duree" >   
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>Part de la phase</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="part de la phase" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.partetap" >   
                            </div>
       <label>Ordre obligatoire</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="ldf"> Oui
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="lpr"> Non
                            </div>
                      
                  
            </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <label> Ordre de la phase : </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ordre de la phase" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.ordretap" >  
                       
                            <div class="form-group">
       <label>du</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.datedebu" >  
                            <label>au</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.dateFin" >          
                            </div>
       <Label>Budget estimatif de la phase :</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Budget estimatif de la phase" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.montesti" >   
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" ng-click="addNewproject(DProjetEtape)">Ajouter</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
<br>      
</ng-form>
        <div class="row" data-ng-hide="!DProjetEtape.length">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="selectedAll" data-ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                            <th class="text-center">
       Ordre
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Phase
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Durée
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Du
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Au
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Estimation
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Date de publication AO
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Date Ouverture des plis
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Taux
      </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr data-ng-repeat="DProjetEtape in DProjetEtape">
                            <td><input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="DProjetEtape.selected"/></td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.ordretap}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.partetap}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.duree}}</td>
       <td>{{DProjetEtape.datedebu}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.dateFin}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.montesti}}</td>
       <td>{{DProjetEtape.datpubao}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.datouvpl}}</td>
                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.tauxavan}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-ng-click="removeproject()" value="Supprimer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre>Form data ={{list}}</pre>
    </div>
    <button type="submit"> dddd</button>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
    
 </div>



<script>
var app = angular.module("DProjetEtape", []);
app.controller("Controller_DProjetEtape",[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.DProjetEtape = [];
    
        $scope.addNewproject = function(DProjetEtape){
            $scope.DProjetEtape.push({ 
             'ordretap': DProjetEtape.ordretap,
             'partetap': DProjetEtape.partetap,
             'duree': DProjetEtape.duree,
             'datedebu': DProjetEtape.datedebu,
             'dateFin': DProjetEtape.dateFin,
             'montesti': DProjetEtape.montesti,
             'datpubao': DProjetEtape.datpubao,
             'datouvpl': DProjetEtape.datouvpl,
             'tauxavan': DProjetEtape.tauxavan
            });            
        };
        var formData;
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.submit = function() {

                 formData = {
             'ordretap': $scope.DProjetEtape.ordretap,
                      'partetap': $scope.DProjetEtape.partetap,
                      'duree': $scope.DProjetEtape.duree,
                      'datedebu': $scope.DProjetEtape.datedebu,
                      'dateFin': $scope.DProjetEtape.dateFin,
                      'montesti': $scope.DProjetEtape.montesti,
                      'datpubao': $scope.DProjetEtape.datpubao,
                      'datouvpl': $scope.DProjetEtape.datouvpl,
                      'tauxavan': $scope.DProjetEtape.tauxavan
           };
                 console.log(formData);
               
           var response = $http.post('/SAO', { DProjetEtape: formData});
           response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.list.push(data);
           });
           response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
           });
           
           //Empty list data after process
           $scope.list = [];
           
          };
        
        $scope.removeproject = function(){
            var newDataList=[];
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
            angular.forEach($scope.DProjetEtape, function(selected){
                if(!selected.selected){
                    newDataList.push(selected);
                }
            }); 
            $scope.DProjetEtape = newDataList;
        };
    
        $scope.checkAll = function () {
            if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
                $scope.selectedAll = true;
            } else {
                $scope.selectedAll = false;
            }
            angular.forEach($scope.DProjetEtape, function (DProjetEtape) {
             DProjetEtape.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
            });
        }; 
    
}]);
</script>


<br>

</body>

</html>

And in the list he show me after submit button : 
Form data =["\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n\r\n<head>\r\n\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\">\r\n\t<title>Création d'un projet</title>\r\n\t<link href=\"/SAO/static/css/bootstrap.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></link>\r\n\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/SAO/static/css/ol.css\" type=\"text/css\"></link>\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/SAO/static/js/ol.js\"></script>\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/SAO/static/js/OpenLayers.js\"></script>\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/SAO/static/js/AngularJS1.2.js\"></script>\r\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/SAO/static/js/jquery.min.js\"></script>\r\n</head>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n   body { background-color:powderblue; }\r\n</style>\r\n<body>\r\n<div class=\"panel-body\">\r\n<fieldset class=\"scheduler-border\">\r\n    <legend class=\"scheduler-border\">Phases/étapes du projet</legend>\r\n    <form data-ng-submit=\"submit()\" name=\"myForm\" data-ng-app=\"DProjetEtape\" data-ng-controller=\"Controller_DProjetEtape\">\r\n<div class=\"row\" >\r\n\t<ng-form>\r\n        \r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"col-md-4\">\r\n     \r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Nom</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Nom\"  data-data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.ordretap\" >   \r\n                            </div>\r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Date de publication AO</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"date\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Date de publication AO\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.datpubao\" >   \r\n                            </div>\r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Date Ouverture des plis</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"date\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Date Ouverture des plis\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.datouvpl\" >  \r\n                            </div>\r\n                       \r\n                \r\n            </div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"col-md-4\">\r\n           \r\n                       \r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Durée estimative</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Durée estimative\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.duree\" >   \r\n                            </div>\r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Part de la phase</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"part de la phase\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.partetap\" >   \r\n                            </div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>Ordre obligatoire</label>\r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n                                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"ldf\"> Oui\r\n                                <input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"lpr\"> Non\r\n                            </div>\r\n                      \r\n                  \r\n            </div>\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"col-md-4\">\r\n\t\t\t<label> Ordre de la phase : </label>\r\n                <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Ordre de la phase\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.ordretap\" >  \r\n                       \r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<label>du</label>\r\n                                <input type=\"date\" class=\"form-control\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.datedebu\" >  \r\n                            <label>au</label>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<input type=\"date\" class=\"form-control\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.dateFin\" >  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n                            </div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<Label>Budget estimatif de la phase :</label>\r\n                            <div class=\"form-group\">\r\n                                <input type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Budget estimatif de la phase\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.montesti\" >   \r\n                            </div>\r\n                            <div class=\"clearfix\">\r\n                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary addnew pull-right\" ng-click=\"addNewproject(DProjetEtape)\">Ajouter</button>\r\n                            </div>\r\n                    </div>\r\n<br>      \r\n</ng-form>\r\n        <div class=\"row\" data-ng-hide=\"!DProjetEtape.length\">\r\n            <div class=\"col-md-12\">\r\n                <table class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\">\r\n                    <thead>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <th><input type=\"checkbox\" data-ng-model=\"selectedAll\" data-ng-click=\"checkAll()\" /></th>\r\n                            <th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOrdre\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPhase\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDurée\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDu\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAu\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEstimation\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate de publication AO\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate Ouverture des plis\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<th class=\"text-center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTaux\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                    </thead>\r\n                    <tbody>\r\n                        <tr data-ng-repeat=\"DProjetEtape in DProjetEtape\">\r\n                            <td><input type=\"checkbox\" data-ng-model=\"DProjetEtape.selected\"/></td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.ordretap}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.partetap}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.duree}}</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>{{DProjetEtape.datedebu}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.dateFin}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.montesti}}</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>{{DProjetEtape.datpubao}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.datouvpl}}</td>\r\n                            <td>{{DProjetEtape.tauxavan}}</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                    </tbody>\r\n                </table>\r\n                    <input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger pull-right\" data-ng-click=\"removeproject()\" value=\"Supprimer\">\r\n            </div>\r\n        </div>\r\n        <pre>Form data ={{list}}</pre>\r\n    </div>\r\n    <button type=\"submit\"> dddd</button>\r\n    </form>\r\n    </fieldset>\r\n    \r\n\t</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script>\r\nvar app = angular.module(\"DProjetEtape\", []);\r\napp.controller(\"Controller_DProjetEtape\",[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {\r\n    $scope.DProjetEtape = [];\r\n    \r\n        $scope.addNewproject = function(DProjetEtape){\r\n            $scope.DProjetEtape.push({ \r\n            \t'ordretap': DProjetEtape.ordretap,\r\n            \t'partetap': DProjetEtape.partetap,\r\n            \t'duree': DProjetEtape.duree,\r\n            \t'datedebu': DProjetEtape.datedebu,\r\n            \t'dateFin': DProjetEtape.dateFin,\r\n            \t'montesti': DProjetEtape.montesti,\r\n            \t'datpubao': DProjetEtape.datpubao,\r\n            \t'datouvpl': DProjetEtape.datouvpl,\r\n            \t'tauxavan': DProjetEtape.tauxavan\r\n            });            \r\n        };\r\n        var formData;\r\n        $scope.list = [];\r\n        $scope.submit = function() {\r\n\r\n                \tformData = {\r\n        \t\t\t\t\t'ordretap': $scope.DProjetEtape.ordretap,\r\n        \t            \t'partetap': $scope.DProjetEtape.partetap,\r\n        \t            \t'duree': $scope.DProjetEtape.duree,\r\n        \t            \t'datedebu': $scope.DProjetEtape.datedebu,\r\n        \t            \t'dateFin': $scope.DProjetEtape.dateFin,\r\n        \t            \t'montesti': $scope.DProjetEtape.montesti,\r\n        \t            \t'datpubao': $scope.DProjetEtape.datpubao,\r\n        \t            \t'datouvpl': $scope.DProjetEtape.datouvpl,\r\n        \t            \t'tauxavan': $scope.DProjetEtape.tauxavan\r\n        \t\t\t};\r\n                \tconsole.log(formData);\r\n               \r\n        \t\t\tvar response = $http.post('/SAO', { DProjetEtape: formData});\r\n        \t\t\tresponse.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {\r\n        \t\t\t\t$scope.list.push(data);\r\n        \t\t\t});\r\n        \t\t\tresponse.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {\r\n        \t\t\t\talert( \"Exception details: \" + JSON.stringify({data: data}));\r\n        \t\t\t});\r\n        \t\t\t\r\n        \t\t\t//Empty list data after process\r\n        \t\t\t$scope.list = [];\r\n        \t\t\t\r\n        \t\t};\r\n        \r\n        $scope.removeproject = function(){\r\n            var newDataList=[];\r\n            $scope.selectedAll = false;\r\n            angular.forEach($scope.DProjetEtape, function(selected){\r\n                if(!selected.selected){\r\n                    newDataList.push(selected);\r\n                }\r\n            }); \r\n            $scope.DProjetEtape = newDataList;\r\n        };\r\n    \r\n        $scope.checkAll = function () {\r\n            if (!$scope.selectedAll) {\r\n                $scope.selectedAll = true;\r\n            } else {\r\n                $scope.selectedAll = false;\r\n            }\r\n            angular.forEach($scope.DProjetEtape, function (DProjetEtape) {\r\n            \tDProjetEtape.selected = $scope.selectedAll;\r\n            });\r\n        }; \r\n    \r\n}]);\r\n</script>\r\n\r\n\r\n<br>\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n\r\n</html>"]
```

Please, if you could help me;

Comment: Do you want to say that in Controller you are not getting DProjetEtape object??

Comment: Yes i woud getting DProjetEtape object it cannot show it in console? and i am using the debug also after submit it can read the function in the controller